# Can I use Chinese Yuans (RMB) in Hong Kong?

Tags: money, china, hong-kong

I just decided to change my plans and I am leaving China to Hong Kong in the next few hours. I still have some Chinese Yuans in my wallet, will those be accepted in Hong Kong or I have to change them to Hong Kong Dollars?